# Pandas Multi Index Dataframe Transform Raw Score into Quantile by Date and add Percentile Column

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, binning

I have a pandas multi index that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to transform the Raw_Score into a percentile, where the comparison is against the day.  So the top score of the day gets a 100, and the bottom score of the day gets at zero, with the other scores proportionately aligned.   I would like to do this at the "all data", "Sector", or "Region" level.  The dataframe would have a new column called "Adjusted_Score".  I think I have to use groupby and quantile, but I am lost.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

**NOTE: Revised to show working code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from datetime import datetime
from numpy import random

# ----------------------------------
# Set up a sample dataframe
# ----------------------------------

def create_df(num):
  # create empty data frame in pandas
  df = pd.DataFrame()

  # add a range of dates
  dates = pd.date_range(start="2022-04-01",end="2022-06-05").to_pydatetime().tolist()
  df['Dates'] = dates

  # generate a random 3 digit Value
  #for i in range(len(dates)):
  df['Raw_Score'] = np.random.randint(-999, 999, size=len(df))

  # generate a random 2 digit Sector between 10 and 15
  #for i in range(len(dates)):
  df['Sector'] = np.random.randint(10, 20, size=len(df))

  # give it a unique value
  df['Region'] = num

  return df

# make a big df
big_df = []

for num in range(10):
  df = create_df(num)
  df = pd.DataFrame(df)

  while num == 0:
    big_df = df.copy()
    num = num + 1
  else:
    big_df = pd.concat((big_df, df), axis=0)


df = big_df.copy()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df.drop_duplicates()

df.set_index(["Region", "Sector", "Dates"], inplace=True)

# ----------------------------------
# Actual Problem Below
# ----------------------------------

# Step 1: Getting rank with groupby:
df['rank'] = df.groupby('Dates')[['Raw_Score']].apply(lambda g: g.rank(method='first'))

# Step 2: Obtain the max value:
df['max'] = df.groupby('Dates')[['rank']].transform(lambda g: g.max())

# Step 3:Calculate percentile by n/N*100:
df['percentile'] = df['rank'] / df['max'] * 100

df
```

Thank you!

Comment: please share the expected output

Comment: I tried to do that in the description of the problem but I was not clear.  Each day has a range of values across Sectors and Regions.  I would like to normalize the raw scores into an adjusted score between 0 and 100 and add that field as an "Adjusted Score".  For extra points, I would like to be able to do this at all three levels of the Multi Index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code:

```
# Generate sample data:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'var': ['a']*10 + ['b']*10,
    'val': np.random.permutation(20)})

# Step 1: Getting rank with groupby:
df['rank'] = df.groupby('var')[['val']].apply(lambda g: g.rank(method='first'))

# Step 2: Obtain the max value:
df['max'] = df.groupby('var')[['rank']].transform(lambda g: g.max())

# Step 3:Calculate percentile by n/N*100:
df['percentile'] = df['rank'] / df['max'] * 100
```

If your dataset is large and you want to speed up the process: `Step 2` simply:

```
subsample = df.groupby('var')[['rank']].max()
df = pd.merge(df, subsample, on=['var'], how='left')
```

For some reason, `merge` in Pandas works much faster than `transform` method

3 level of multi-index follows the same code above

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer.  I wish I had your coding skills!  I edited the original posting to incorporate your answer and am getting a Value error: Can not reindex from a duplicate axis.  Could you elaborate on what you meant by "3 level of multi-index follows the same code above"?

Comment: @RockportRedfish: I mean `groupby(['var1', 'var2',..])`

Comment: Thank you @PTQuoc.  My issue was with the index in the original df I set up.  I modified the code to reindex and your solution worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by @PTQuoc.  Original code modified to reflect working answer.